# Close div if another with the same name showing on

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hide

I would like to write a script that detects whether a given div is already open and if so, closes the previous one and opens a new one. The class name when the div is open is .collapse in, and the class name of the div that shows is

```js
(function () {
  $('.collapse in').on ('click', function() {
    $(".accordianNav").each(function() {
      $(this).find(".accordianNav").hide();
    });
  });
})();
```

I tried to write something like that but its not working. I am new and need a easy tip or full solution.

TPL ps_mainmenu.tpl

```js
//DOESN'T WORK
(function () {
  $('.collapse in').on ('click', function() {
    $(".accordianNav").each(function(){
      $(this).find(".accordianNav").hide();
    });
    });
})();


//mobile menu
var burgerBtn = document.getElementById('burgerBtn');
var mobile = document.getElementById('mobile');
var full_screen_opacity = document.getElementById('full-screen-opacity');
burgerBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  mobile.classList.toggle('navigation');
  document.body.classList.toggle("noscroll")
}, false);

full_screen_opacity.addEventListener('click', function () {
  mobile.classList.toggle('navigation');
  document.body.classList.toggle("noscroll")
}, false);
```

```css
#burgerBtn {
  border-top: 2px solid #f94c01;
  height: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -khtml-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#burgerBtn:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 30px;
  left: 0;
  background: #f94c01;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -khtml-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#burgerBtn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 30px;
  left: 0;
  background: #f94c01;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -khtml-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#nav {
  /* was absolute */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  z-index: 10;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 30px 0px 0 -10px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
 
}

#nav li {
  height: 30px;
  width: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: #eae8e5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
  -khtml-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
}

#nav li+li {
  margin-left: -40px;
}

#nav li+li+li {
  margin-left: -80px;
}

#nav li+li+li+li {
  margin-left: -120px;
}
#nav li+li+li+li+li {
  margin-left: -140px;
}
#nav li+li+li+li+li+li {
  margin-left: -160px;
}

.navigation #nav li {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navigation #burgerBtn {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navigation #burgerBtn:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -khtml-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 33px;
  left: -2px;
}

.navigation #burgerBtn:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -khtml-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  bottom: 11px;
  width: 33px;
  left: -2px;
}

ul#nav {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

div#mobile {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- ps_mainmenu.tpl  -->

{assign var=_counter value=0}
{function name="menu" nodes=[] depth=0 parent=null}
    {if $nodes|count}
      <ul class="top-menu" {if $depth == 0}id="top-menu"{/if} data-depth="{$depth}">
        {foreach from=$nodes item=node}
            <li class="{$node.type}{if $node.current} current {/if}" id="{$node.page_identifier}">
            {assign var=_counter value=$_counter+1}
              <a
                class="{if $depth >= 0}dropdown-item{/if}{if $depth === 1} dropdown-submenu{/if}"
                href="{$node.url}" data-depth="{$depth}"
                {if $node.open_in_new_window} target="_blank" {/if}
              >
                {if $node.children|count}
                  {* Cannot use page identifier as we can have the same page several times *}
                  {assign var=_expand_id value=10|mt_rand:100000}
                  <span class="float-xs-right hidden-md-up">
                    <span data-target="#top_sub_menu_{$_expand_id}" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
                      <i class="material-icons add">&#xE313;</i>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                {/if}
                {$node.label}
              </a>
              {if $node.children|count}

              
              <div {if $depth===0} class="sub-menu js-sub-menu mega-menu collapse toggle" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="collapseone"
                {else} class="collapse" {/if} id="top_sub_menu_{$_expand_id}" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="collapseone">  <!-- podkatalogi -->

                <div class="accordianNav">
                  <ul>
                    {menu nodes=$node.children parent=$node}
                  </ul>
                </div>


              </div>

            

              {/if}
            </li>
        {/foreach}
      </ul>
    {/if}
{/function}


    <div class="menu js-top-menu position-static hidden-sm-down" id="_desktop_top_menu">


        {menu nodes=$menu.children}

        
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

<!-- ps_header.tpl  -->


<div id="mobile" class="row hidden-md-up" >
              
              
              <div id="burgerBtn" ></div>
              
             
              <nav id="nav" class="has-children">
                <div class="js-top-menu mobile" id="_mobile_top_menu"></div>
                
              </nav>

            










              
                 {hook h='displayNavFullWidth'}
              </div>
```

```
<div class="menu js-top-menu position-static hidden-sm-down" id="_desktop_top_menu">


    {menu nodes=$menu.children}

    
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: PS... it's *"accordiOn"* not *"accordiAn"*. Also `in` is an invalid tagName. Did you mean class: `.in`? or `.on`? Mind to share a [mcve] of some HTML and CSS? This problem was already covered hundreds of times here on Stack Overflow. I really believe there are duplicates around. Have you made an extensive research on the problem? Also, there's no need to wrap your code into an IIFE `(function () {})();` Just use the inner function. Or rather, if needed wrap in a DOM ready: jQuery($=> { /*code goes here*/ });

Comment: could you pls provide your html or sample?

Comment: The problem is i am editing a prestashop code whre they using their own HTML (TPL) but i will add it there

Comment: `$('.collapse').on('click', function() {  $(".accordianNav").hide();  });` if you insist on spelling it `accordian` instead of `accordion`